# How can I apply a watermark on every page of a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, watermark

I have a PDF file and want to apply a watermark like the following on all pages and at 45 degrees:

```
watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark
watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark
watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark
watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark
watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark
watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark watermark
........................
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 30):

You can use [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/451289/258054). Sample command line:

```
pdftk original.pdf stamp watermark.pdf output final.pdf
```

It is especially convenient if you are on Linux as pdftk is included in many popular distributions.

For Windows users there is also [free GUI version](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) available.

#### More Options

Instead of stamping watermark over original document you can add it as background using `background` command (original pdf must be transparent). There is also a possibility to apply multi-page watermarks. Here is the documentation for the relevant commands:

```
  background <background PDF filename | - | PROMPT>
     Applies a PDF watermark to the background of a single input
     PDF.  Pass the background PDF's filename after background
     like so:

     pdftk in.pdf background back.pdf output out.pdf

     Pdftk uses only the first page from the background PDF and
     applies it to every page of the input PDF.  This page is
     scaled and rotated as needed to fit the input page.  You can
     use - to pass a background PDF into pdftk via stdin.

     If the input PDF does not have a transparent background (such
     as a PDF created from page scans) then the resulting back-
     ground won't be visible -- use the stamp operation instead.

  multibackground <background PDF filename | - | PROMPT>
     Same as the background operation, but applies each page of
     the background PDF to the corresponding page of the input
     PDF.  If the input PDF has more pages than the stamp PDF,
     then the final stamp page is repeated across these remaining
     pages in the input PDF.

  stamp <stamp PDF filename | - | PROMPT>
     This behaves just like the background operation except it
     overlays the stamp PDF page on top of the input PDF docu-
     ment's pages.  This works best if the stamp PDF page has a
     transparent background.

  multistamp <stamp PDF filename | - | PROMPT>
     Same as the stamp operation, but applies each page of the
     background PDF to the corresponding page of the input PDF.
     If the input PDF has more pages than the stamp PDF, then the
     final stamp page is repeated across these remaining pages in
     the input PDF.
```

Comment: That's great and correct but I spent a long while trying to get this to work... Turns out the Mac version on their site has been broken since 2016 while they have a working fix... Ugh. See this stack overflow answer which might save some time for other Mac users such as myself who might have run into your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750883/pdftk-hanging-on-macos-sierra

Comment: Note that the free version for windows does *not* support watermarking. This is only available in the pro version.

Comment: This doesn't work properly. Watermark is overlapped to the main content.

Comment: @rahim.nagori That's what watermark is, a figure that's overlapped/stamped over document. You can put semi-transparent image into the watermark.pdf so that original content can be seen through it.

Comment: Okay so, how do I add a background to the current pdf file?

Comment: @rahim.nagori I've updated the answer with more options that should answer your question.

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy , Thanks a lot

Comment: Super late to the party, but I would add you need a watermark.pdf to make it work. Silly me I did not understand this at the first try. You can create one with (e.g.) Libre Office Writer (Format > Watermark...) and export as "watermark.pdf". +1 anyway ;)

Answer (score 10):

Using [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/):

```
qpdf --overlay overlay.pdf --repeat=1 -- input.pdf output.pdf
```

Alternatively

```
qpdf --underlay underlay.pdf --repeat=1 -- input.pdf output.pdf
```

See [documentation](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.overlay-underlay).

Answer (score 3):

Many ways:

- Use a commercial program ([random example](http://www.coolpdf.com/pdfwatermark.html))
- Use whatever tool was used to create the PDF (e.g. [Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/acrobat/articles/acr8at_background.html))
- Convert the PDF to a more tractable form.

  - e.g. [pdftops](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/home.html) or [pdf2ps](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/index.html) - then edit the PostScript to add the [watermark](http://www.tailrecursive.org/postscript/draft.html) and convert back to PDF

Comment: Hey, that's pretty cool. Do you know other solutions (2019) ? I want to make a linux command tool to add a watermark on pdf, but i don't know how to do. I watched PostScript and i'm actually trying to make it.

Comment: @Kub. There must be other solutions by now but I'd just find them by googling in the usual way. I quite like doing this using Postscript but I'd probably use [go](https://golang.org/) rather than [perl](https://www.perl.org/) nowadays to create a program to insert watermarks into PS. You can probably work directly with PDF if you either spend long enough studying PDF or if you find a convenient PDF library/module/package for your preferred programming language (e.g. something like [UniPDF](https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf)).

Answer (score 0):

Create a PDF with your watermarks and stamp the original PDF with such a tool: http://pdftools.softonic.de/

Comment: problem is softonics like cnet now, have a junk installer

Comment: is that sheelapps thing the same as the foxtab software, the latter wants you to install IE9. very strange. the  sheelapps  pdftools thing I only see on softonic or cnet. have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the PDF file with Libreoffice (*Draw* will be used by default), and then export to PDF. In the dialog that appears, enter the watermark you wish to have.

Answer (score 0):

pdftk works fine in windows. the important step is to create a transparent background with a non-transparent logo/watermark in it. for example  you can open a standard new page (8.5x11) in photoshop, make the background opacity 0,  insert the watermark or image at the position that you like at opacity 100 or less and then save it (as PDF) logo.pdf

use the command line as suggested
pdftk original.pdf stamp logo.pdf output final.pdf

done
you'll get a merged PDF with only the logo at the position that you saved the photoshop document , repeated on each page of the original pdf

note: if the background is not transparent then obviously the logo.pdf will replace the original pdf

Answer (score -1):

You may be interested using [Dysprosium](http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Downloads.html#part10) free software, I found useful.

- You can select one page or selected pages or all pages of your document to be watermarked.
- You can have the same text for those pages or different texts for each page.
- You are able to watermark, as desired by your question, in many lines using different angles, fonts, and colours
- Similarly, if you choose to watermark with images.
- You can watermark one document with pages from another pdf document.
- Using this software, you can convert an image or a set of images to pdf and then over-lay or under-lay the resulting pdf to your document.
- You are able to decide for the font, colour, angle, opacity, and scale of watermark.
- Software does not overwrite the original file, keeping it safe.
- Software is non-commercial, unlimited, lightweight, and portable and cross-platform as a JAR file.

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Just tried this on Windows 10, but the interface seems to be all messed up and I don't see any watermark option at all

Answer (score -1):

**You can use Adobe Acrobat Pro to add watermark on all or only a few pages of your PDF file.**

You'll find this in the menu View / Tools Sets / Default Tools. Then the option to add watermark will be in the "pages" section on your sidebar.

It gives you the option to rotate your text, use any style or size you want, add it in front or behind the text, etc.

You can also use an image if you prefer.

Finally, you can save that watermark as a profile if you need to use it on other projects.

Make sure to keep a duplicate of your original file before testing this!

[image: Adobe Acrobat Pro PDF watermarks]