# Merge elements of 2 pdf pages in single one

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I've 2 A4 pages from pdf.

The first one contain the "content" of the page and second contain header and footer.

Is it possible via command line to merge the content of these 2 pdf pages into a new single one that contains all the element of the 2 pages ?

Comment: Not sure about commandline, but there are pdf editors that can use one pdf as "background" and merge with another pdf on top.

Comment: I think i've founded a possible solution with iText here : https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/superimposing-content-from-one-pdf-into-another-pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [gettalong](https://superuser.com/users/776262/gettalong), I've found the tool qpdf to make this, referenced in this post : https://superuser.com/a/1640241/696066

```
qpdf --overlay overlay.pdf --repeat=1 -- input.pdf output.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [watermark command](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/documentation/reference/hexapdf.1.html#watermark) from HexaPDF for this:

```
$ hexapdf watermark -w header_footer.pdf content.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks but I see this work in ruby. And I want a standalone program. I've founded one : https://superuser.com/a/1640241/696066

Comment: On macOS Ruby is already present and I guess on many Linux distributions, too. So after installing HexaPDF via `gem install hexapdf`, it just works. But it is not a compiled application, yes.