# Apply watermark to every pdf on a directory

Tags: linux, pdf, watermark

I've learned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/280659/how-can-i-apply-a-watermark-on-every-page-of-a-pdf-file) to apply a watermark to a pdf file without opening it by doing:

```
pdftk input.pdf stamp watermark.pdf output output.pdf
```

Now I wanted to do this to every .pdf on a given directory, either substituting the original .pdfs or creating newer ones with the same names + something like `-WM.pdf`

But this command requires an input file name and output file name, so I don't know how to do a `for` loop for it.

On **Linux**.

Comment: Linux, sorry, I forgot! I'll edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop like this:

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdftk "$file" stamp watermark.pdf output "WM-$file"; done
```

Comment: -.-' That was not complicated... I've been trying for more than half an hour... xD. I thought that would apply the command to the files themselves, but that I would need to do something different to get the filename for the output... and I was getting "Input errors, so no output", so I thought I was already failing at searching the files... Anyway, **Thank you very much!** Clearly I'm not good understanding computing logic!

Comment: Recommended reading; "Bash guides" at www.tldp.org - slightly old but still a jumpstart for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users a similar result would be at console

```
for %f in (*.pdf) do pdftk "%f" stamp watermark.pdf output "%~dpnf-wm.pdf"
```

or in a script

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) do pdftk "%%f" stamp watermark.pdf output "%%~dpnf-wm.pdf"
pause
```

if there are problems you should watch for feedback by use `pause` such as

```
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   create-forms-sample.pdf
   OWNER PASSWORD REQUIRED, but not given (or incorrect)
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Likewise PDFtk can lock up on some files, but that is rarer

> Error: Failed to open PDF file:
> f1040-fred